# jQuery ajax no cache works on localhost, but not on server

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching, localhost

With jQuery ajax method I have a request on some file, which returns data in json format. That request is triggered by clicking on some button. Then  I display that data as I need.
Everything works fine on localhost, but when I moved my project to the server, there was a little problem. The data, which was updated in database and should be shown in that file (formatted in json), does not update, until I refresh the page.

Here is the code:

```
function myAjaxFunction() {

$.ajax({
    'url' : 'MY_URL',
    'type' : 'POST',
    'cache' : false,
    'data' : 'MY_DATA'
    'dataType' : 'json',
    'success' : function(result) {
     // my code here
    }

});

}


var body  = $("body");
body.on('click', '.some_button', function(e) {
    myAjaxFunction();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

And I wonder, is that because, I cache body tag?

Comment: The problem probably lies somewhere else... it's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add to end of your 'MY_URL' some parameter with random number

```
'url' : 'MY_URL&amp;'+Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1),
```

Comment: or add header with no-cache on asnwer page

Comment: What if I add that parameter in 'data' attribute, not in 'URL' ?

Comment: I agree, the page you are requesting is probably getting cached, you should add a random appendix to the url so it is seen as a new url

Comment: @deerua well, I changed my url to this

`'url' : 'ClientService&amp;'+ Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1)`

and in console, it showed me an error, the page was not found.

`POST http://localhost:8080/myproject/ClientService&amp;69 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: 'ClientService?&amp;'+ Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1)

Comment: I thought this is what jQuery AJAX already did by default (when `cache` is `false`, using the `_` URL parameter).